# Generalizing a surjection ${\bf GL}(2,\Bbb R)\cong (\bf M,\circ)$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Consider the set of all invertible $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb R$ (I think we can do it over $\Bbb C$ but I didn't look at it) $${\bf GL}(2,\Bbb R)=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}  a&b \\c &d\end{matrix}\right):a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R,ac-bd\neq 0 \right\}$$

Consider now the set $\bf M$ of all functions of the form

$$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

again with $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R,ad-bc\neq 0 $. If we identify each of these with a matrix 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}  a&b \\c &d\end{matrix}\right)$$ then we can define an isomoprhism between $\rm GL$ and $(\bf M,\circ)$ as groups with operations of matrix multiplications and functional composition, respectively, and identities$$\left(\begin{matrix}  1&0 \\0 &1\end{matrix}\right)=e$$
$$x=\frac{1x+0}{0x+1}=e'$$ 
since if $$\eqalign{
  & f = \frac{{ax + b}}{{cx + d}}  \cr 
  & g = \frac{{ex + f}}{{gx + h}} \cr} $$ then $$f \circ g = \frac{{\left( {ae + bg} \right)x + af + bh}}{{\left( {ce + dg} \right)x + dh + cf}}$$
which corresponds to

$$\left(\begin{matrix}  a&b \\b &c\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}  e&f \\g &h\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}  ae + bg&af + bh \\ce + dg &dh + cf\end{matrix}\right)$$
and similarily for inversion, $${f^{ - 1}} = \frac{1}{{ac - bd}}\frac{{dx - b}}{{ - cx + a}}$$

and $$\left(\begin{matrix}  \frac  d\Delta& \frac {-b}\Delta \\\frac{-c}\Delta &\frac a\Delta \end{matrix}\right)=e$$

I include the determinant $\Delta=ac-bd$ inside the matrix to avoid any multiplication by scalars considerations.

**My question is**: How can this be generalized to ${\bf GL}(n,K)$, and what is the theoretical relevance of this? I know Möbius Transformations are important in Complex Analysis, for instance, but I haven't seen any "higher dimesional" equivalent around.

**ADD** As users noted, for every $a\in \Bbb R$,$$\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto x$$

so the isomoprhism is actually obtained by quoting ${\bf GL}(2,\Bbb R)$ by $I=\{aI_2:a\in\Bbb R\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an isomorphism but just a surjective map $f : \textrm{GL}_2(\Bbb{R}) \longrightarrow \textbf{M}$. The kernel of this map is all scalar multiples of the identity (as you can check) and so by the first isomorphism theorem,

$$\textbf{M} \cong \textrm{GL}_2(\Bbb{R})/ \{ aI\}$$

where $a$ ranges over all non-zero real numbers. The group on the right is called $\textrm{PGL}_2(\Bbb{R})$ (if you are working over $\Bbb{R}$). The generalisation of this is of course when you consider $\textrm{GL}_n(\Bbb{C})/\{aI\}$ that (as you may have guessed) is called $\textrm{PGL}_n(\Bbb{C})$.

I don't really know much about this group except that if you have $\textrm{GL}_n$ acting on say $\Bbb{R}^n$, then you can ask what the associated action will be on the quotient $\Bbb{R}\textrm{P}^{n-1}$ space. Now recall that real projective space $\Bbb{R}P^{n-1}$ is the space of all lines through the origin in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Suppose we let a scalar multiple of the identity act on one of these lines. Then the line just get sent to itself yes? Rather, every element on the line is sent to a scalar multiple of itself. However in terms of projective space, that line is considered as ***just one point*** and so any scalar multiple of the identity matrix ***becomes*** the "identity matrix"  on $\Bbb{R}P^{n-1}$. That's why we quotient it out to get that the "actual group" acting on $\Bbb{R}P^{n-1}$ is $\textrm{PGL}_{n}$.

Comment: Yes, I missed the fact that $$\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&a\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto x$$ for each $a$. Could you add a little about ${\bf PGL}_n(K)$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff But you do have an isomorphism between the quotient and the group of mobius transformations.

Comment: What do you mean when you say action? Do you mean a function of the form $\star:K\times V\to V$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff The action of $\textrm{GL}_n$ on the vector space is the usual one given by left multiplication of matrices.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

This map isn't an isomorphism; all scalars are sent to the identity. The generalization goes by the name of the [projective general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group); this naturally acts on projective space, hence the name, and is the natural target for [projective representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation), which are important for example in quantum mechanics.

Comment: I have just started linear algebra this quatrimester, so I'd appreciate if you explain some of the above. I know the basics about groups, rings, integral domains and fields to get to define vector spaces, but not much more of abstract algebra than that. For example, I don't understand what "naturally acts on", "the natural target for" mean.

Comment: @Peter: can you ask a more specific question? What I mean is that the action of $\text{GL}(V)$ on $V$ induces various other actions functorially, e.g. the action of $\text{GL}(V)$ on the projective space $\mathbb{P}(V)$ of lines in $V$. This action factors through the projective general linear group $\text{PGL}(V)$ because scalars all act trivially on lines. The second use of "natural" may be regarded as a definition of projective representation.

Comment: Oh, well. My point is I know too little algebra to understand what you're telling me. What does "factors through" mean, for example? I don't about "functors" either, so maybe I'll have to wait a little till I come back to look at this. Also, I now realize that one thing is not clear in my question. I wanted to know what functions correspond to the $n$th dimensional generalization. Maybe a multivariate version of Möbius' Transformations?

Comment: @Peter: it means that the map $\text{GL}(V) \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}(V))$ is the composition of a pair of maps $\text{GL}(V) \to \text{PGL}(V), \text{PGL}(V) \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}(V))$. Again, all I am really saying is that the scalars act trivially on projective space. The functions you want are, as I said, precisely the elements of the projective linear group. These are the appropriate generalization of Mobius transformations to higher dimensions.

Comment: @Peter: in three dimensions elements of the projective linear group may be written down explicitly as pairs of rational functions $\left( \frac{ax + by + c}{dx + ey + f}, \frac{gx + hy + i}{dx + ey + f} \right)$, and this generalizes to higher dimensions. But this gets less useful the higher up you go; it really is better to think about projective space.